# How to get different ids to svg paths in same component in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have a timeout button component in angularjs, it seems to work fine but when I have two buttons in the same page like below, **the two timers will "mess" with each other arc paths**.

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
   <timeout-button button-title="send sms" call-rest="sendSms()"
                    timeout="20">
   </timeout-button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
   <timeout-button button-title="send mail" call-rest="sendMail()"
                    timeout="30">
   </timeout-button>
</div>
```

My timeout-button component:

```
<div class="timeoutParent">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" 
            ng-click="callFunction()">
      <span>{{ buttonTitle }}</span>
    </button>
    <div class="svgButton" ng-if="timeoutButtonCtrl.timerOn">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
        <circle ng-show="circleVisible" cx="100" cy="100" r="100" />
        <path id="arc" stroke-width="20"/>
        <text x="100" y="120" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90">
              {{timeout}}
        </text>
      </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
  $scope.callFunction = function () {
    $scope.callRest && $scope.callRest();
    countdown();
    $scope.timerOn = true;
  };

  $scope.countdown = function () {
    $scope.circleVisible = $scope.timeout == $scope.count ? true : false;
    $scope.timer = $timeout(function () {
      $scope.timeout--;
      countdown();
    }, 1000);
    var arc = document.getElementById('arc');
    if (!arc) {
      return;
    }
    if ($scope.timeout <= 0) {
      $timeout.cancel($scope.timer);
      $scope.timerOn = false;
      $scope.timeout = $scope.count;
      return;
    }
    var angle = 360 * ($scope.timeout / $scope.count);
    $('#arc').attr('d', describeArc(angle));
  };
```

How do I get different indexes for my ids even though I'm not using ng-repeat?

Comment: Easiest is to wrap your button in shadowDOM so IDs are scoped (mind you ``document.getElementById('arc')`` won't work then). Otherwise you have to generate unique IDs ``let id = crypto.randomUUID()`` within each component